# Is there a way in Ipython notebook to show LaTeX files inline?

Tags: latex, ipython, inline

For month or more I have used Ipython notebook for proceeding measurement data and found it quite effortless for creating plots with matplotlib, by seeing them instantly in Ipython notebook. For tables I use matrix2latex which then I use to include to my long latex document. Since I usually can't get my tables to show up as I wish at first time I lose quite a time compiling my long LaTeX file.

So the question is:

Are there a way to show all latex formatted file inline python notebook which I could use for plotting a matrix2latex generated file?

Answer (score 1):

As IPython is simply using MathJax for LaTeX display, it is limited to the math family of commands.  matrix2latex outputs LaTeX tables of the form:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \toprule
        $1$ & $1$\\
        $2$ & $4$\\
        $3$ & $9$\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

This being said, if you need to have some pretty printing of matrices, then I would suggest something like this:

```py
from IPython.core.display import Math
m = eye(10)
display(Math(latex(m)))
```

Comment: That would be a great workaround if only the sympy Matrix module could accept elements formated in latex. Specifically I use $\pm$ in my elements which is passed to matrix2latex.